# Why cannot create icons dynamically in ajax?

Tags: ajax, dynamic, getjson, popover, dynamic-content

Normally, when I write the followings:

```
 <a id="sta_numberOfIcons" class="icon-user" rel="popover"></a>
```

And js:

```
 $("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){

    $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title:"Passenger Info",
        content: "content "+$(this).attr('id') 
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });

  });
```

It works and I can see a popover for the icon.But when I write the following code,to create the icons dynamically, but I cannot show popovers for the newly created icons.

html part:

```
Stations:
 <select name="selectStation" id="selectStation" onchange="sta_callStation(this);"></select>

      <a id="sta_numberOfIcons" class="icon-user" rel="popover"></a>
      <div id="infoOfPassengers"></div>
      <div id="distType"></div>
      <div id="distParams"></div>
```

In Stations combobox, options are filled when the page is loaded.They are filled normally.

js function for getting the number of passengers from php, and create icons accordingly:

```
function sta_callStation(sel){
 $('#noOfPassengers, #infoOfPassengers, #distType,#distParams').empty();
   $('#sta_numberOfIcons').empty();
      $.getJSON('Stations.php', function(station){

        $.each(station, function(sta_key, sta_value) {

        if(sel.value==sta_key)
        {
          $.each(sta_value.passengers, function(j,passengers) 
        {

         var pas_icon = document.createElement("a");

          pas_icon.className ='icon-user';
          pas_icon.id='id_'+j;

          pas_icon.setAttribute('href', '#');
          pas_icon.setAttribute('rel', 'popover');
          //alert('id_'+(j));
          var empty=document.createElement("a");
          empty.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
          document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(pas_icon);

          document.getElementById('sta_numberOfIcons').appendChild(empty);

      });
        }

  });

  });
  }
```

The icons appear in the page under the combobox.I just put  to try, I don't know how to insert the new created icons to a tag.I just appended the newly created icons to  tag.What is wrong here?Why I cannot show popovers for the created icons?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS code that you have which successfully wires-up the `popover` for elements `$("a[rel=popover]")` needs to execute **after** you have dynamically added your icons.

You could paste those lines into the end of the logic in `sta_callStation()` but it is probably better to put them into their own function and call that from `sta_callStation()`.

Something like:

```
function bindMyPopovers() {
    $("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){
    $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title:"Passenger Info",
        content: "content "+$(this).attr('id') 
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });

  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Can I ask one more question?How can I fill the content of the popover from another php file?For example I have Passenger.php file in which there are passenger id, from, where etc.,I can use the same structure above, like Stations.php I can write getJSON.But where the bindMyPopover() must come after calling showPassenger() or before showPassenger().?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do (based on your ___comment___), then you also need dynamic content for the `content:` of the Popovers.  It looks to me like the `popover` plugin has some built-in support that would provide the easiest way to do what you want.  Look closely at the section called __Loading AJAX Content__ at http://daveyijzermans.nl/jquery/popover/demo.html#usage_modifying

Comment: I couldn't still load content with Ajax.:/Thanks anyway